VSCode with SQL Developer extension ORA-17190 error
In VSCode on Windows 11 using the SQL Developer extension I get error
'Error: An error occurred when attempting to connect to the database.The following error occurred: ORA-17190: Connection property format error: Property is 'v$session.osuser' and value is 'Username(Domain'
https://docs.oracle.com/error-help/db/ora-17190/.Consult your database documentation for information on how to resolve the specified error code'
I'm trying to log in using Oracle auth, I've seen this before with SQL Developer where I had to add a VMOption line to the ide.conf file but I dont see any equivalent in VSCode.
Tried different users and credentials plus variants on the hostname.

How do you mean, Oracle auth?

So in VSCode I'm authenticating with an Oracle username and password, the error is suggesting its trying my domain credentials somewhere.

Resolved, I needed to add an advanced parameter for the key and value and now it works.

